# NameError: name 'QgsApplication' is not defined in python standalone script

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I have this standalone script to display shapefile. I followed the qgis python cookbook procedure, but i got this error. "NameError: name 'QgsApplication' is not defined". Here is my whole code. Someone please tell me where am wrong. I verified my setPrefixPath by running it in Qgis python console

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import sys, os

class Mapbox(QMainWindow):    
    def __init__(self, shapefile):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Map Box Viewer")
        canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
        canvas.useImageToRender(False)
        canvas.setCanvasColor(Qt.white)
        canvas.show()

        layer = QgsVectorLayer(shapefile, "layer1", "ogr")
        if not layer.isValid():
            raise IOError("Invalid shapefile")

        QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
        canvas.setExtent(layer.extent())
        canvas.setLayerSet([QgsMapCanvasLayer(layer)])        
        self.setCentralWidget(canvas)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)        
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis", True)        
QgsApplication.initQgis()        
viewer = Mapbox(r"shapefile.shp")        
viewer.show()

app.exec_()        
QgsApplication.exitQgis()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the import statement for the `QgsApplication`, add `from qgis.core import QgsApplication`. This may give you an `ImportError` if your `qgis.core` is not in your enviroment variables, the process to fix this vary depending on your operational system

Also, `QgsApplication` is a subclass from `QApplication` so you do not need to use both. Here's what you can do:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import QgsApplication, QgsMapCanvas, QgsVectorLayer, QgsMapLayerRegistry, QgsMapCanvasLayer
import sys, os

class Mapbox(QMainWindow):    
    def __init__(self, shapefile):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Map Box Viewer")
        canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
        canvas.useImageToRender(False)
        canvas.setCanvasColor(Qt.white)
        canvas.show()

        layer = QgsVectorLayer(shapefile, "layer1", "ogr")
        if not layer.isValid():
            raise IOError("Invalid shapefile")

        QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
        canvas.setExtent(layer.extent())
        canvas.setLayerSet([QgsMapCanvasLayer(layer)])        
        self.setCentralWidget(canvas)

app = QgsApplication(sys.argv, True)  # the second arg "True", says that you are using a interface
app.setPrefixPath("C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis", True)  # Use forward slash in paths or os.path
app.initQgis()        
viewer = Mapbox(os.path.abspath("shapefile.shp"))  # QgsVectorLayer needs the absolute path to create a valid layer
viewer.show()

app.exec_()        
app.exit()
```

I have add some minor changes to the code.

Side note: QGis and PyQt are different things, PyQt is a python api of [Qt](https://www.qt.io/). It is used to create interfaces, QGis makes use of PyQt to make its interfaces